# how we combine two data frame in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have two data sets. so how can i combine these data sets

```
df.show()

----+---+----+----+---+-----+-----+
|  _1| _2|  _3|  _4| _5|   _6|   _7|
+----+---+----+----+---+-----+-----+
|yyyy| mm|tmax|tmin| af| rain|  sun|
|1941|  1| ---| ---|---| 74.7|  ---|
|1941|  2| ---| ---|---| 69.1|  ---|
|1941|  3| ---| ---|---| 76.2|  ---|
|1941|  4| ---| ---|---| 33.7|  ---|
|1941|  5| ---| ---|---| 51.3|  ---|
|1941|  6| ---| ---|---| 25.7|  ---|
|1941|  7| ---| ---|---| 53.9|  ---|
|1941|  8| ---| ---|---| 91.8|  ---|
|1941|  9| ---| ---|---| 25.5|  ---|
|1941| 10| ---| ---|---|106.2|  ---|
|1941| 11| ---| ---|---| 92.3|  ---|
|1941| 12| ---| ---|---| 86.5|  ---|
|1942|  1| 5.8| 2.1|---|114.0| 58.0|
|1942|  2| 4.2|-0.6|---| 13.8| 80.3|
|1942|  3| 9.7| 3.7|---| 58.0|117.9|
|1942|  4|13.1| 5.3|---| 42.5|200.1|
|1942|  5|14.0| 6.9|---|101.1|215.1|
|1942|  6|16.2| 9.9|---|  2.3|269.3|
|1942|  7|17.4|11.3|---| 70.2|185.

df2.show()
+----+---+----+----+---+-----+---+
|  _1| _2|  _3|  _4| _5|   _6| _7|
+----+---+----+----+---+-----+---+
|yyyy| mm|tmax|tmin| af| rain|sun|
|1853|  1| ---| ---|---| 57.3|---|
|1853|  2| ---| ---|---| 32.3|---|
|1853|  3| ---| ---|---| 65.5|---|
|1853|  4| ---| ---|---| 46.2|---|
|1853|  5| ---| ---|---| 13.2|---|
|1853|  6| ---| ---|---| 53.3|---|
|1853|  7| ---| ---|---| 78.0|---|
|1853|  8| ---| ---|---| 56.6|---|
|1853|  9| ---| ---|---| 24.5|---|
|1853| 10| ---| ---|---| 94.8|---|
|1853| 11| ---| ---|---| 75.5|---|
|1853| 12| ---| ---|---| 39.1|---|
|1854|  1| ---| ---|---| 78.9|---|
|1854|  2| ---| ---|---| 38.8|---|
|1854|  3| ---| ---|---| 41.2|---|
|1854|  4| ---| ---|---|  4.5|---|
|1854|  5| ---| ---|---| 73.5|---|
|1854|  6| ---| ---|---|115.4|---|
|1854|  7| ---| ---|---|133.1|---|
+----+---+----+----+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: you can use union. df1.union(df2)

Comment: What means combine? If you want to append it you can use `df1.union(df2)` since both have the same number of columns

Comment: Also for your datasets consider the option `header="true"` when reading the data, since it seems your first row contains the column names but it is treated as normal records

Comment: Thanks alot Ali yesilli & Gaw. actually recently i am using pyspark so that why i put such question anyways you guys really gem :)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by other folks you can use union function which uses position to combine your data frames. However, with spark 2.3 they have released another function "unionByName", which resolves columns by name (not by position).

Reference for the same can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName).

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: Dear Neeraj,  if i have 10 files with same data structure. so how we compile all files in pyspark because its too difficult to use union function for each file.

Comment: @HimanshuBajaj if you have files of the same data structure then probably read all the files at once as dataframe. You might not even required to do union. I have answered the question if union is required.  For e.g. you have multiple csv files in some location then you can use "df = spark.read.csv("<path to folder>"/*.csv)" to create the dataframe. if you have any specific required do let me know I can try to help.

Comment: If it resolves your problem, could you please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks Neeraj its work. appreciates for your response :)

Comment: Thanks Himanshu for your confirmation. Could you please accept the answer since it is working for you.

Comment: if you have 10 files with the same structure, just do read.json at the directory level.